# iphone not to display the Q of QuickTime when embeding an mp3 file in a UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, quicktime

My iPhone app has a UIWebview in which I use the embed html tag for an audio mp3 file. When the app launches, a "Q" is displayed where the embed html tag.

Question: 
Is it possible to replace the Q being displayed with an image or make the Q not show up?

Thanks